# Two MongoDB queries same result, what is the difference?

Tags: mongodb

I'm playing around with mongoDB and I can't figure out what is the difference between my two queries.

I use following collection:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("520b79869971eb1a0fdd0ad4"),
    "created" : 1376483718636,
    "updated" : 1376483718636,
    "firstName" : "Jakob",
    "lastName" : "D",
    "email" : "jakob.d@test.com",
    "emailValidated" : false,
    "phoneNumber" : "",
    "lastLogin" : 1376483718624,
    "linkedProviders" : [ 
        {
            "userId" : "1XXXXXXXX6",
            "providerId" : "facebook",
            "password" : "",
            "salt" : "",
            "authMethod" : "oauth2",
            "avatarUrl" : ""
            }
        ],
        "userRoles" : [ 
            "ADMIN"
        ]
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("520b7dd09971ebcd35dd0ad6"),
    "created" : 1376484816666,
    "updated" : 1376484816666,
    "firstName" : "Jakob",
    "lastName" : "D",
    "email" : "jakob.d@test.com",
    "emailValidated" : false,
    "phoneNumber" : "",
    "lastLogin" : 1376484816666,
    "linkedProviders" : [ 
        {
            "userId" : "jakob.d@test.com",
            "providerId" : "userpass",
            "password" : "7e4aff9e0d90db2318ffcc689c11b66d",
            "salt" : "N1GgNvy3NnS0i5GFDyglQZ9s4CeFNndn",
            "authMethod" : "userPassword",
            "avatarUrl" : ""
        }
    ],
    "userRoles" : [ 
        "ADMIN"
    ]
}
```

The two queries that gives me the correct and same result(**the one with objectId 520b79869971eb1a0fdd0ad4**) are:

```
db.users.find({"linkedProviders.userId":"1XXXXXXXX6","linkedProviders.providerId":"facebook"})


db.users.find({"linkedProviders": {"$elemMatch": {"userId":"1XXXXXXXX6" },"$elemMatch": {"providerId":"facebook" }}})
```

So what is the difference between these two?

Comment: In second query you have an object with a duplicate key.

Comment: The `$elemMatch` key is used twice, so the first value `{"userId":"1XXXXXXXX6"}` is ignored.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The difference is that `$elemMatch` finds items for one single array element.

This solution:

```
db.users.find({
    "linkedProviders.userId": "1XXXXXXXX6",
    "linkedProviders.providerId": "facebook"
})
```

Finds any user that has that userId and that providerId, but possibly in different items in `linkedProviders`, e.g., if `linkedProviders[0].userId` matches the first and `linkedProviders[1].providerId` matches the second part of the query, the full document (i.e., the user) will match that query.

On the other hand,

```
db.users.find({
    "linkedProviders": {
        "$elemMatch": {
            "userId": "1XXXXXXXX6",
            "providerId": "facebook"
        }
    }
})
```

will match only if the index values (0 and 1 in the previous example) are the same in the document, i.e., only if one array element matches both.

When there's only one key-value mapping in the `$elemMatch`, it should do the same as the query with the key-value mapping applied directly.

More information:
http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/elemMatch/#op._S_elemMatch